What distinguishes a Master from a Goon?
In the movie John Carpenter's Vampires, the slayer Jack Crow and his crew separate the monsters they hunt into two categories- masters and goons, however the movie itself is rather vague on how one differs from the other.
For example, are goons former humans that were 'turned' by a master? Is it possible for a goon to eventually become a master? The film was supposedly based on a novel, maybe the book has more information?

In the movie, it is said that Valek turned into a vampire through a "reverse exorcism" that somehow failed. So that would be one way to become a Master. The book has some hints relative to goons, but a bit vague too. Chapter 11: "Then there was the tale ifself, all about half-formed goons (they couldn't be full vampires yet from her peeling-cheek description) stomping around the downtown Cleburn square chewing on people.". Chapter 14: "They were goons, still. All of them. Too recently dead to have thoughts or ideas or notions or sense of self.". So perhaps something relative to time.
